# facebook login with facebook c# sdk doesn't work on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to include the option to share some acutivies of my WP7 app on facebook. For this I have [downloaded](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) the Facebook C# SDK and I'm currently over the authentication phase.

I have followed the WP7 example but then I run the app the login button of the facebook page isn't working. Is this a bug in my code, in the facebook sdk or a facebook bug?
I have uploaded a test project to my [SkyDrive](http://cid-311e65521cc75cc9.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=311E65521CC75CC9!1685) account.

Thanks for the help.

Best regards,
Ralf

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"?. Does it not respond to input, does nothing happen?

Comment: Yepp, the login button on the facebook page doesn't do anything. I have set a breakpoint in the Navigating-event of the webbrowser control. The breakpoint does not get hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the WebBrowser definition (in XAML) to this:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" 
       Name="FacebookLoginBrowser" 
       Navigated="FacebookLoginBrowser_Navigated"
       LoadCompleted="FacebookLoginBrowser_LoadCompleted"
       IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```

The last item is the key. WP7's WebBrowser control defaults to having scripting off. Facebook login requires it.

(Please mark me as the answer if it solves your problem.. it worked for me)

Comment: it works. Sorry for my late replay - I was the last days very busy (CeBIT visit etc).

Answer (score 0):

You may have run into a Visual Studio bug (or your folders were not packaged up properly and I am the only one seeing this ;). Try this:

- Launch notepad, and edit `FacebookTest\FacebookTest.csproj' (as a text file)
- Halfway down in the file, the is an `<ItemGroup>` containing `<Reference ...>` tags
- Add a reference `<Reference Include="mscorlib" />`
- Save, (re)start Visual Studio

At this point, I was able to build your code, but deploying and running may require additional steps.

Comment: I don't see any problems with my project example. It's a normal silverlight wp7 project (so you need the wp7 dev tools) with the facebook sdk libraries (included in the libs folder).

Comment: I have the WP7 dev tools, but was unable to build your code until I applied the fixes in this answer. Have a look at the other answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact behavior I saw when I trying to authenticate with the C# Facebook SDK in Windows Phone 7. When you load Facebook's auth page into a BrowserControl a page loads with a button, but tapping on the button does nothing - the page with the token in the never loads (in contrast with my nearly identical WPF project).

Comment: I see, I'm not the only one who has the problem.